# Google Search Bar Android

Tags: android, search, android-actionbar, android-recyclerview

I am trying to replicate the Google search bar movements as well as design as shown in the link below.Sorry i couldn't post the actual gif here,i couldn't figure out how to.

[Demo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mtALf.jpg)

Comment: Look at this tutorial: https://mzgreen.github.io/2015/02/15/How-to-hideshow-Toolbar-when-list-is-scroling(part1)/

Answer (score 1):

I presume you're looking for something like this

[image: http://antonioleiva.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/collapsing-toolbar-layout.gif]

If so then the idea is to use a `android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout`
inside of a `android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout`.

Follow this [tutorial](http://antonioleiva.com/collapsing-toolbar-layout/) and you it would be done.

Hope that helped :)

Comment: I added a picture now,i am trying to emulate the search bar so when a person scrolls up the search bar should scroll up and hide but the moment a scroll down is performed it should immediately show up

Comment: Just do the same thing as the tutorial but instead of putting an image put your search bar and make the rest transparent